Trying to install UBUNTU on Windows 10 PC
am trying to get away from Microsoft. I have downloaded your UBUNTU file, ubuntu-24.04-desktop-amd64.iso, and have used Rufus to install it on a thumb drive, successfuly. But when leaving it in the USB slot, and clicking Shift, and Restart, and selecting use a Device, and Install Ubunto, it starts installing without selecting the partition I made for Ubuntu. I never get to the point where I am able to make a Dual boot etc.
Can anyone help?

How did you make the "partition I made for Ubuntu"? Is it available space on the disk, or space on a Windows Volume?  How large is it? Does booting in "Try Ubuntu" mode work?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
